# Typescript differences between import statements and paths

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a class that I want to import somewhere ("example.ts"):

```
export class Example {
  constructor() {
  }

  public someFunction() { }
}
```

Can someone tell me the differences between those three import statements from typescript?

1. `import * as example from "./example.ts"`
2. `import { example } from "./example.ts"` or `import { example } as example from "./example.ts"`
3. `import "./example.ts"`

There are also differences for the path names:

4. `"./example.ts"`
5. `"example.ts"`
6. `"example"`

When exactly do I have to use which path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say `example.ts` looks like this:

```
export const PI = 3.14
export function sayHello() { console.log('hi'); }
export default function() { console.log('i am default'); }
```

1. `import * as example from "./example"` - this takes everything exported from `example.ts` and makes it available under `example` variable. Therefore you will write things like `example.sayHello()` or `example.PI`. You may be wondering where is the default export. This one is under `default` key therefore you can access it using `example.default()`
2. `import { PI, sayHello } from "./example"` this way you import only specific parts from `example.ts`. In this example only PI variable and sayHello function. You can call it directly: `sayHello()`
3. `import "./example"` - this is used to basically execute the file. For example when there are some side effects. For example in rxjs we use `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` to modify rxjs observable prototype and add the map operator. Exports are not important - the execution is important. This matters especially in nodejs environment where this get transpiled to `require('./example')`.

I will modify your examples a bit here:

4. `"./example"` - refers to file in the same directory. You will usually use it to import your modules.
5. `"example"` refers to so called non-relative module. These are resolved either relative to `baseUrl` in your `tsconfig.json` or using path mapping. Typically path mapping maps to your `node_modules` so you can import your libraries. Therefore you will use this one usually for importing external modules.
6. `"example.ts"` - in typescript the import filename is not allowed to end with `.ts`. Therefore just use 4. or 5.

Here is [reference in TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).