# Why can't I import and use my class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

My class is defined as follows:

```
export class Log {
    email: string;

    constructor(email: string) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

In a separate file, I import my class as follows:

```
import * as Log from "../models/Log";
```

But then, when I try to use my class eg:

```
function log(log: Log, callback: Function) {

}
```

I get an error 'cannot find name Log'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yesterday I answered question related to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264753/typescript-differences-between-import-statements-and-paths/47265126#47265126 Check it out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{}` to specify which class to import from the file. So...

```
import { Log } from "../models/Log";
```

imports the class `Log` from the file `../models/Log`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I agree, but was in a hurry, sorry :)